# Этмология слова "отчебучить"

Tags: этимология

Интересно, а как появилось слово "отчебучить"? От какого оно происходит?
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://diderix.petergen.com/lub-sahrw.htm
Отчубучить, гл. = побить (от сл. чубук, которым в старину дрались помещики)http://www.mirslovushakova.ru/search_char/%EE/15/
(простореч. устар.). Поколотить, избить (первонач. чубуком крепостного слугу). ...Словарь Ушакова. 
Чубуки были не только виноградные, но и черешневые. Видимо, так называли и тонкий прут, и любую полую палку. Курительные чубуки - любые полые стержни для насадки трубки.

Answer (score 2):

Чубуки, чебуки - черенки для винограда.  http://enc-dic.com/ushakov/Otchubuchit-43649.html
  "Отчубучить" -  `Толковый словарь Даля`- отдуть, прибить чубуком.
 Отсюда в переносном смысле -отчебучить,отчубучить - совершить что-л. неуместное, позволить себе какую-л. выходку. `Малый академический словарь`-

Comment: Ой, сомнительно как-то...
При чем тут черенки да и откуда на Руси виноград? 
А кроме Даля такую идею кто-нибудь даёт?